# Stream filtering changing log file in realtime

Tags: logs, filter, streaming, real-time

I have `file.log` with this sample:

```
11-Feb-2022 18:34:42 lorem uneeded5
11-Feb-2022 18:34:43 water uneeded6
11-Feb-2022 18:34:44 ipsum uneeded7
11-Feb-2022 18.34.45 waterfall uneeded8
```

I expect output `filtered.log`
with this sample

```
1644579283 water
1644579285 waterfall
```

So basically filter I want is:

`cut uneeded lines` (I tried `grep`)

`cut uneeded column` (I tried  `cut`)

`convert date string to timestamp` (I tried `date`)

Don't worry I know how to cut and convert it. The problem is, Its stream and redirect the output with pipelining or stdout or tee etc. I'm confused with it.

Here what I did.

```
tail -f file.log | grep --line-buffered "water" | tee temp.file | cut -d' ' -f1,2 | date +%s -f- | paste -d' ' - temp.file | cut -d' ' -f1,4 >> filtered.log
```

Why It doesn't work? When there's incoming new line in `file.log`, `filtered.log` still blank.

Here explanation of that command in theoritically acording my brain:

- `tail -f` for stream or get incoming new line.
- `grep --line-buffered` filter line that contain water.
- `tee temp.file` create temporary file so that I can paste it later.
- `cut -f1,2` get column 1 and column 2 only for convert to timestamp later with `date`
- `date` convert timestamp from previous output (cut output)
- `paste` paste/merge timestamp to the first column temp.file that I backup before.
- `cut` cut uneeded column

I suspect this is buffering issue, idk how to use buffer. I tried `stdbuf` but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

From my previous work in question, basically I just need `stdbuf` for every pipeline. Idk why should we need stdbuf.

```
stdbuf -oL tail -f file.log | grep --line-buffered "water" | tee temp.file | stdbuf -oL -i0 cut -d' ' -f1,2 | stdbuf -oL -i0 date +%s -f- | stdbuf -oL -i0 paste -d' ' - temp.file | stdbuf -oL -i0 cut -d' ' -f1,4 >> filtered.log
```